# Java - interface passing itself as a parameter

Tags: java, interface

What about an interface that passes itself as a parameter in a method? How das that work? I always thought that an interface is abstract - so how can it be used just like that inside a method?

The only [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074143/java-implementation-of-interface-with-methods-passing-interface-parameter) I could find according to that topic did not really satisfy me.

```
public interface Comparable{
     boolean compare(Comparable comparable);
}
```

Comment: In order to use any interface there must be a concrete type; it is the concrete type that is *actually* passed.

Comment: An interface reference (like this `comparable`) is just a reference to an object that implements that interface.